# Adding metadata to markdown text

Tags: html, metadata, markdown

I'm working on software creating annotations and would like my main data structure to be based around markdown.

I was thinking of working with an existing markdown editor, but hacking it so that certain tags, i.e. `[annotation-id-001]Sample text.[/annotation-id-001]` did not show up as rendered HTML; the above would output `Sample text.` in an HTML preview and link to a separate annotation with the ID `001`.

My question is, is this the most efficient way to represent this kind of metadata inside of a markdown document? Also, if a user wants to legitimately use something like `"[annotation-id-001]"` as text inside of their document, I assume that I would have to make that string syntax illegal, correct?

Comment: why not use a markdown link then? `[Sample text.](#annotation-id-001)`

Comment: OP, please explain in more detail what you mean by "annotations". if you mean footnotes, this is already covered by markdown.

Comment: mb21's suggestion is brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what Markdown parser you use but you can abord your problem with different points of view:

- first you can "hack" an existing parser to exclude your annotation tags from "classic" parsing and include them only in a certain mode
- you can also use the internal "meta-data" information proposed by certain parsers (like [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) or [MarkdownExtended](http://github.com/piwi/markdown-extended)) and only write your annotations like meta-data with a reference to their final place in content
- or, as mentionned by *mb21*, you can use simple links notation like `[Sample text.](#annotation-id-001)` or use footnotes like `[Sample text.](^annotation-id-001)` and put your annotations as footnotes.

Comment: without more information about OP's use case, the third bullet point seems like by far the best solution.